# How to pass date arg to my cloudbuild yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

My `cloudbuild.yaml` exists of the following:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports', 'gs://testing-reports/$BUILD_ID']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
   args: ['-m', 'rm', '-r', 'gs://studio360-testing-reports/latest']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports', 'gs://testing-reports/latest']
```

This way I always have my latest report seperated from the older ones. But can I pass a {date} arg or something into my first line so I can have a visual order of all the older reports?

(Because there is no way to rank the files by last modified in the gcp storage/bucket)

Thanks

Comment: You could try using variables values defined by you. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) you will find more information about it. Keep in mind you will need to follow a set of rules when defining user-defined variables. Let me know if this is what you are asking for! I hope it helps.

Comment: I am looking in to it, I tried a substitution _FOO = bar and it started building but just stopped at the beginning of the step with the substitution. I don't see no clear errors only at the end of my log it says

``` CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred. ```

You got any clue? Also: I'm not sure how to put a var date can I just use something like var date = new Date();?

Comment: Can I just use something like var date = new Date();? It's not possible to add variables like that in the cloudbuild.yaml. Your best bet is to use [user-defined substitution](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions). The problem might be related with unmatched keys. Please make sure to follow the rules presented in the documentation to avoid mismatched keys when building your cloudbuild.yaml. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the first block to this:

`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['-m', 'cp', '-r', '/workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports', 'gs://testing-reports/${_DATE}_$BUILD_ID']`

Then run this:

`gcloud builds submit . --substitutions _DATE=$(date +%F_%H:%M:%S)`

Then you would have something like this in the bucket:

`gs://testing-reports/2020-02-13_14:01:40_8a6a7ed0-62e0-43ed-8f97-aa6eca9c2834`

Explanation [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions).

---

**EDIT:**

---

For automatic builds started by Cloud Build triggers, use this `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    gsutil -m cp -r $FILENAME gs://$BUCKET/$FILENAME-$(date +%F_%H:%M:%S)-$BUILD_ID
```

This allows the builder to use `bash` to execute `gsutil`, so the `bash` command "`date`" can be used inside the command.

Good explanation of the syntax by Googler [here](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf), and info about entrypoint [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#entrypoint).

---

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for @asbovelw, it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: You save my life haha thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you should be able to bash out and do something like this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
  - -c
  - |
    gsutil -m cp -r /workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports gs://testing-reports/$BUILD_ID-$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
```

To my knowledge, you can't run system commands in sub. variables or env. variables. (or at least I haven't been able to figure out how)

Comment: sadly this doesn't work either, it just append the literal string

Comment: How are you running the build? via the CLI? Or a github trigger?
I run via Git trigger and it works just fine for me... could try this? (seems redunant though)



`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
  - -c
  - |
        echo $(date +%m-%d-%Y) > /workspace/my_date && 
    gsutil -m cp -r /workspace/api-testing/target/cucumber-html-reports gs://testing-reports/$BUILD_ID-$(cat /workspace/my_date)`

Comment: I made a step to echo the date, touch the file with the date, then show and here are the results: 

`Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/cloud-builders/metadata:latest
gcr.io/cloud-builders/metadata:latest
2020/02/13 14:54:09 Started spoofed metadata server
2020/02/13 14:54:09 Build id = localbuild_f943b41f-5fd2-4237-9b6a-b6e362e4b2dc
2020/02/13 14:54:09 status changed to "BUILD"
BUILD
: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
: 02-13-2020
: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 13 20:54 myfile-02-13-2020.txt`

(ps - I ran this locally)

Comment: I forgot to add, you might have to escape the command and add two "$" (so - `$$(date)`)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Lance Sandino I used the solution above (automatic cloud build) but thanks for the effort!